# Multiple HTML Files In One HTML File?

Tags: file, html, document-body

Is it possable to have a part of a html file visable until a link text is pressed and the original is removed?

> i have tried to use a program to do it but all it does is comprees them into one **.exe** and when open extracts them and opens the index file then when it is closed it deletes the tempory extracted files **:(**

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

If you have php in your server you can include them using php

```
include("somePage.php")
include("anotherPage.php")
```

So all you have to do its rename the .html pages into .php pages and include them if your server is php.

Edit: Since you cant use serverside you may use this (Client side part) : http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Comment: this is in a local suite not a server, its just a basic alpha test for the development of a competitor of "**Onlive**", Thanks Anyway!

Comment: Then i think you'll need a serveside language to do it :-/

Comment: Editted my response in case you cant use serverside

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
You can do it using Javascript or jQuery.
At first set display:none to the code which you want to show onClick. Now on mouse click, lunch a function which will do 2 things 1 after another: 
 1. At first existing code will be hidden by change of css style to display:none
 2. Then the hidden code will be displayed by change of css style to display:block

Hope it answers your Query :)